# Is this possible to execute a test regularly in a controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, cllocationmanager

With my application I take the coordinates of my user when he is in movement in order to display him the traject he took. But my problem is to know when the user stops in order to stop the current traject and display him this trajectory on a map.

My code to know when the user starts his trajectory works perfectly well, I do it with `didUpdateLocations` with a distanceFilter of 100.

My problem is I can't know when user stop.
I want to know if for example there is a solution to know when I will no get any update locations anymore and so this will mean that the traject is over.
I tried with the `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates`, but my program seems to never enter to this function.

//Here is my code that gets the update of the user location

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    if !self.isTrajectStarted {

        if self.locations.count == 0 {
            print("First coordinate")

        } else if (self.locations.count == 1) {

            if self.locations[0].distance(from: mostRecentLocation)>150 { 
                print("traject begin")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print(" New location is %@", mostRecentLocation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing current location value with the previous one in didUpdateLocations?

Comment: if my user doesn't move I will no get his location because i set a distanceFilter to 100m. So between two coordinates there is minimum 100meter in distance so it can't really help

Answer (score 0):

Write a new logic to detect the stop.

`locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates`, won't get called immediately after a stop. It is usually called after 5 minutes (not documented, this number is what I have seen in my apps).

You need to write a logic by first categorizing the mode of travel. If your app records user's movement in a vehicle, you would know that whenever speed drops to below 4-5 mph, user is either on a traffic signal or has reached on the destination. If you don't get any new update for next 5 minutes or so, conclude it to be a stop, or else continue recording.

Try taking advantage of the [motion sensor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionactivity) as well by appending it to your logic, where it could tell you different activity types such as walking, driving, stationary etc.